# intellij 13.1.1 hang on window7 64bit

Tags: intellij-idea

I used intellij 13.1.1 on window7 64bit(32G memory).
Sometimes when I'm editing .vm file(velocity template file), intellij hang suddenly.
And then I restarted intellij.

As far as I experienced, editing with java source files and other files are OK.
how should I do?

P.S. below is my vmoptions.

idea64.exe.vmoptions

```
-Xms4096m
-Xmx10240m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: -Xmx10240m seems a little high. I use 750m (on a project ~ 2,000 classes w/ weblogic + remote debugging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, upgrade to 13.1.2 ([release notes](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+13.1.2+Release+Notes)) that was release a couple of days ago. That version fixes a [Mac specific hang](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122793) (reported by a co-worker of mine) and a [hang on Windows](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123354) when opening projects that I reported. Those (or other fixes) may solve your issue. (I'm not seeing any Velocity specific fixes).

I agree with @d33j In the 10+ years of IDEA usage and daily forum visits & reading of bug reports (*yes, I am obsessed with IntelliJ IDEA*), the #1 cause of Hangs is people tweaking their VM options, and especially setting them too high. I *highly recommend* leaving all the default settings and only bump up the `-Xmx` to 750m on a 32-bit machine, and maybe to 900m on a 64-bit machine using a 64-bit JDK and the idea64.exe. Any higher and you get GC pauses and other issues. I (and all my co-workers) have been using those settings for years with multiple very large complex projects open without any issues.

If after adjusting you still have issues, go to your log directory (*Help > Show log*). When a hang occurs, IDEA will output thread dumps. So you should see a `threadDumps` directory with a current date and timestamp. Take a look at those and see if anything jumps out. In particular, anything in a third party plug-in.

The second biggest cause of hangs is an error in third party plug-ins. Disable any third party plug-ins. (*Settings > [IDE Settings] Plugins* and change the `Show` dropdown to "Custom"). Disable all of those and restart. If the issue goes away, use a binary search to locate the problematic plug-in.

If none of the above solves the issue, Follow the instructions from the JetBrains support document [Reporting performance problems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems) and/or [Getting a thread dump when IDE hangs and doesn't respond](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348667) to submit the issue to them. Also attach your threadDump directory (as mentioned above) and log file.

Comment: Hi, Mark Vedder. I upgraded 13.1.2 and modified only -Xmx:1024m and -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8. I have never met hanging any more so far. thanks.